# Modular Program Design - Combining Monad Transformers in Monad Agnostic functions

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am trying to come up with a modular program design and I, once again, kindly request your help.

As a follow-up to these following posts [Monad Transformers vs passing Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968351/monad-transformers-vs-passing-parameters-to-functions) and [Large Scale Design in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077866/large-scale-design-in-haskell/3077912#3077912), I am trying to build two independent modules that use Monad Transformers but expose Monad-agnostic functions, then combine a Monad-agnostic function from each of these modules into a new Monad-agnostic function.

I have been unable to run the combining function e.g. how do I call `mainProgram` using `runReaderT` in the example below ?.

The subsidiary question is: is there a better way to achieve the same modular design goal ?

---

The example has two mock modules (but compiles), one that performs logging and one that reads an user input and manipulates it. The combining function reads the user input, logs it and prints it.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

module Stackoverflow2 where

import Control.Monad.Reader

----
---- From Log Module - Writes the passed message in the log
---- 

data LogConfig = LC { logFile :: FilePath }

doLog :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader LogConfig m) => String -> m ()
doLog _ = undefined


----
---- From UserProcessing Module - Reads the user Input and changes it to the configured case
----

data  MessageCase = LowerCase | UpperCase deriving (Show, Read)

getUserInput :: (MonadReader MessageCase m, MonadIO m) => m String
getUserInput = undefined

----
---- Main program that combines the two
----                  

mainProgram :: (MonadReader MessageCase m, MonadReader LogConfig m, MonadIO m) => m ()
mainProgram = do input <- getUserInput
                 doLog input
                 liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Entry logged: " ++ input
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `mainProgram` signature is problematic, because the `MonadReader` typeclass contains the functional dependency `MonadReader r m | m -> r`. This essentially means that a single concrete type cannot have a `MonadReader` instance for multiple different types. So when you say that the type `m` has both instances `MonadReader MessageCase` and `MonadReader LogConfig` it goes against the dependency declaration.

The easiest solution is to change `mainProgram` to have a non-generic type:

```
mainProgram :: ReaderT MessageCase (ReaderT LogConfig IO) ()
mainProgram = do input <- getUserInput
                 lift $ doLog input
                 liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Entry logged: " ++ input
```

This also requires the explicit `lift` for `doLog`.

Now you can run the `mainProgram` by running each `ReaderT` separately, like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let messageCase = undefined :: MessageCase
        logConfig   = undefined :: LogConfig
    runReaderT (runReaderT mainProgram messageCase) logConfig
```

If you want to have a generic function that uses two different `MonadReader` instances, you need to make it explicit in the signature that one reader is a monad transformer on top of the other reader.

```
mainProgram :: (MonadTrans mt, MonadReader MessageCase (mt m), MonadReader LogConfig m, MonadIO (mt m), MonadIO m) => mt m ()
mainProgram = do input <- getUserInput
                 lift $ doLog input
                 liftIO $ putStrLn $ "Entry logged: " ++ input
```

However, this has the unfortunate effect that the function is no longer fully generic, because the order in which the two readers appear in the monad stack is locked. Maybe there is a cleaner way to achieve this, but I wasn't able to figure one out from the top of my head without sacrificing (even more) genericity.

Comment: Thank you; very clear explanation on why `mainProgram` is not 'runnable'. That is what I feared: you have to either give up genericity or encapsulate one Monad Transformer within another and `lift`. I am sure that both solutions will fit 99% of my needs, but it is too bad it is not trivial building n-level generic modules by simply combining other generic modules.

Comment: I accepted your answer since you were the first one to respond, you explained why my example could not be run, you covered the usual cases and your answer was largely upvoted by the community. Again, thank you, but I wish I could accept dflemstr reply too since he answered the second part of the question by providing a generic mechanism.

Answer (score 22):

There is a way to write a fully modular version of the program. The way you need to approach the problem is to bundle up your reader configuration into one data structure, and then define type classes that describe the partial interface that specific functions need towards that data structure. For example:

```
class LogConfiguration c where
  logFile :: c -> FilePath

doLog :: (MonadIO m, LogConfiguration c, MonadReader c m) => String -> m ()
doLog = do
  file <- asks logFile
  -- ...

class MessageCaseConfiguration c where
  isLowerCase :: c -> Bool

getUserInput :: (MonadIO m, MessageCaseConfiguration c, MonadReader c m) => m String
getUserInput = do
  lc <- asks isLowerCase
  -- ...

data LogConfig = LC { logConfigFile :: FilePath }
data MessageCase = LowerCase | UpperCase

data Configuration = Configuration { logging :: LogConfig, casing :: MessageCase }

instance LogConfiguration Configuration where
  logFile = logConfigFile . logging

instance MessageCaseConfiguration Configuration where
  isLowerCase c = case casing c of
    LowerCase -> True
    UpperCase -> False

mainProgram :: (MonadIO m, MessageCaseConfiguration c, LogConfiguration c, MonadReader c m) => m ()
mainProgram = do
  input <- getUserInput
  doLog input
  liftIO . putStrLn $ "Entry logged: " ++ input
```

Now you can call `mainProgram` with a `Configuration` in a `ReaderT` monad and it'll work as you would expect.

Comment: Impressive! Thank you. So the 'trick' is to *not* combine Monad Transformers but rather combine all the data structures in one (in `Configuration`) and rely on type classes to expose the 'API'. Out of curiosity, is this a common pattern in designing Haskell applications ?

Comment: No, it is uncommon to need such a general and loosely-coupled design for a small configuration problem such as this one; however when larger systems require this level of modularity, this is that pattern that is used. See, for example, the Snap web framework, and how Snaplets are configured.

Comment: OK. Many thanks. Working on large Java applications, over the years, I have become sensitive to having modules written with a "standard" pattern to facilitate their maintenance and improve their re-usability.

Comment: I accepted shang answer - he was the first one to reply and covered the first part of my question - but I wish I could accept your answer too which provides a generic mechanism. Once again, thank you.