# Combining ReaderT monads?

Tags: haskell, monads

It seems that it would be useful to be able to combine different ReaderT environments.

For instance, a generic logging facility might look something like this:

```
logit :: Text -> ReaderT Bool  IO ()
logit str = do debugflag <- ask
               liftIO $ if debugflag then putStrLn ("debug: " ++ str) else return ()
```

This looks like a nice reusable component. So how would I go about integrating this definition with another ReaderT environment so that I could use both of them?

For instance, suppose I want to combine it with this ReaderT instance:

```
foo :: ReaderT Text IO ()
foo = ...
```

so that I can use both `foo` and `logit` in the same function.

Comment: Please check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007123/modular-program-design-combining-monad-transformers-in-monad-agnostic-function)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to layer them into a stacked monad, but they can't be stacked together since both of them declare that `IO` is exactly the wrapped monad. Fortunately, your code is already general enough to lift this restriction. The most general types of your functions use `MonadIO` instead of specifically using `IO`. If you change the types to

```
 logit :: MonadIO m => Text -> ReaderT Bool m ()
 foo   :: MonadIO m =>         ReaderT Text m ()
```

then the `liftIO` call will lift the `IO` actions through the entire stack to an `IO` monad at the bottom.

To be clear, the types you've written do not need to use `liftIO`—the same type would be satisfied by just `lift`, but since `IO` is (trivially) an instance of `MonadIO` then your (overly) specialized type will also pass the checker.